# Как пользоваться гитхабом в команде?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Если, пока я работаю над проектом, кто-то что-то запушит в репозиторий, то, если это потом попытаюсь сделать я, яполучу ошибку "У вас устаревшкая версия репозитория, используйте git pull сначала" или что-то такое. Но при этом, если я использую git pull, я получаю ошибку "У вас есть несохранённые изменения".

Часто бывает так, что я сам себе всё ломаю забывая написать `git pull` перед началом работы или `git push` после её завершения. (Я работаю с двух ОС на одном компьюетере, обмениваясь файлами через гитхаб, потому что потом гитхабом же отправляю на виртуальный сервер.) Я полагаю, что такой инструмент как гитхаб не должен иметь такого банального неудобства, из чего делаю вывод, что я что-то делаю не так. Что же?

Comment: github здесь не при чем. Все что Вы описываете - это обычная робота новичка с git. Пробовали начать с чтения документации https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2 ?

Comment: А зачем в вашем случае вообще гитхаб? Для синхронизации файлов есть много других сервисов: dropbox, google drive, тысячи их. Более того, если две ОС на одном компьютере, выделите общий раздел с данными.

Comment: просто не недо сидеть в одной ветке и пушить раз в неделю, работайте в своей отдельной ветке или создавайте по ветке на "feature” и возьмите себе за правило - каждое более менее гранулярное измененние, или перед каждым пререрывом а работе делайте по коммиту и не забывайте названия к коммитам делать такие, чтобы потом Вы же по этим названиям могли понять какие изменения содержатся в коммитах

Comment: @Mullo специально от ответа "общий раздел с данными" я пояснил, что гитхабом так же заливаю файлы на хостинг, из-за чего унифицированный метод обмена файлами мне кажется рациональнее. Зачем мне общий раздел под 1 небольшой проект?